# How can I make a max-height 0 transition nice for a 1 line div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a div which is 1 "line" in height. When a button is clicked I want it to disappear and at the same time another div with more lines shall appear. I got it to work BUT regardless what I do the 1 line div disappears EXTREMELY fast in a way so that its almost like if I use no transition at all. For teh multi line div it works great though.

So my question here is what can I do so that the transition into not showing is nice for the 1 line div *(nice being that it disappears slowly instead of just whoosh and gone it is. As a note here it HAS to also disappear placewise so that the place it used is no longer in use that is why I chose the max-height way originally)*?

**html code:**

```
    <div id="Simple" class="Hide Show">
        <div>1. simple</div>
    </div>
    <input type="Button" OnClick=" $('#Simple').removeClass('Show');$('#Advanced').addClass('Show');" value="Switch" />
    <div id="Advanced" class="Hide">
        <div>1. advanced</div>
        <div>2. advanced</div>
        <div>3. advanced</div>
        <div>4. advanced</div>
    </div>
```

**css classes:**

```
.Hide {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Show {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.7s ease-in;
}
```

Link to a fiddle with teh code:
https://jsfiddle.net/7u12yvm0/

As information there also: I'm using internet explorer (it should also work for IE11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows

```
transition: max-height 0.7s ease;
```

and

```
<input type="Button" OnClick=" $('#Simple').hide('slow').removeClass('Show');$('#Advanced').addClass('Show');" value="Switch" />
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/fLs700c1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery fadeOut

```
$('#Simple').fadeOut('slow');$('#Advanced').addClass('Show');"
```

Comment: Problem with that solution is it slowly fades out but then the placing of the content below changes from one moment to the other (with a "jump" so to say)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u12yvm0/3/)

Your setting a really large max-height. All of the max height is animated when you click the button.
Thats why it took so long to animate.

Setting: `max-height: 20px;` is a respectable height to have on one line of text.

How you can just tweak your transition timer to how long you want it.